# Show submenu in another block

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-theming

I have a Drupal 7 CMS with a Navigation build with nice_menus (http://drupal.org/project/nice_menus).

My main menu has several links and each link has several sub links.

These sublinks should be shown to the user in a block.

Any advice on how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Menu Block module should handle this - http://drupal.org/project/menu_block

Go to your blocks page, click add new menu block and fill in the form and then use it like any other block.

To show just sub menu items of a main item make a menu block of the menu and set the **starting level** to the level you want to show. To show JUST these items use the **maximum depth** field.

Comment: okay this works perfect!
Another Question: i want a different image displayed at the same place on each menuitem.
So if i click "about me" i want a picture a displayed at the right side and if i m on "news" i want another picture.
Is there also a plugin?

Comment: Get the id and do it in the CSS with background images and padding. That's how I'd do it...

Comment: this should be configurable in the settings.